# Interpreting classif.ce results in mlr3

Tags: machine-learning, classification

I've used `mlr3viz::autoplot()`to produce a benchmark visualisation below:
[plot of classif.ce vs mlr3 learners](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jz6NG.png)

I initially thought the graph indicated xgboost was a better performing model but when I run this model the confusion matrix is not as good as the logistic regression confusion matrix.
Is a higher classif.ce value on this graph a useful indicator of better model performance or am I barking up the wrong tree?
Thanks

Comment: You're using different metrics to evaluate the models, so you can't expect the results to be consistent. The benchmark also gives you a range of classification errors.

Comment: lower classification error indicates better performance.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff Where do you see that he is using multiple measures?

Comment: @PaulCollins As missuse pointed out, CE is better when its lower. Otherwise we can really help you here as we do not know what you did / why you did it.